# Write datetime.datetime object to a file

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py, python-datetime

### Problem

I want to write a datetime.datetime object to a file, because my bot is down over night and I need it to check through all messages from that point of time until current messages but I found no solution how I could do this. The File Type doesn't matter as long as I can write the datetime.datetime object to it and can read it from it (but I would prefer JSON as I already got a system for writing, reading,... for this).

### Tried

I tried to write it as raw datetime.datetime to a JSON File and tried to write it as raw datetime.datetime to a txt File with `.write()` which both didn't work because they don't accept that type.

### Current code

At shutdown of the bot:

```
async for message in channel.history(limit=1):
    lastmsg = message.created_at

jsonhandle.update("last_message", lastmsg, "lastmsg")
```

Called with `on_ready`:

```
last_message = jsonhandle.get("last_message", "lastmsg")

    chistory = await channel.history(after=last_message).flatten()
```

Comment: What about writing the datetime  object  as isoformat string to the json? You'll just need to convert back to datetime when loading the json

Comment: @MrFuppes So how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Format the `datetime` object as string by adding `.strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")` at the end.

Now you can save it to any file using `write()`

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
    file.write(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)"))
```

for reading the file you have to parse it using `strptime`

```
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(file.read(), "%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")
```

Comment: But the question is if discord.py is gonna accept it because it is a string and not datetime.datetime

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the reading the time
@FlexGames when you write the object to file, you will convert to string and while reading it you have to convert it back to datetime object using strptime.
I do not think any errors will arise.

Comment: Until now everything working fine, gonna test it out later with the complete functionality

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to format the `datetime` object as a string and write that:

```
import datetime

# Write the datetime
date = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 28, 18, 37, 4, 127747)
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write(date.isoformat())

# Read it back
with open(file_name) as f:
    date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(f.read())
```

In this example, the file will contain `2021-03-28T18:37:04.127747`.

Comment: I know, but I am not sure if discord.py is gonna accept this as it is not datetime.datetime object but a string

Comment: @FlexGames, your question says "I want to write a `datetime.datetime` object to a file" - what string are you talking about?

Comment: You are converting the datetime.datetime object to a string, I want it directly written into the file because I am not sure if discord.py can handle strings as datetime

Comment: @FlexGames, the `# Read it back` part reads the string and converts it to `datetime.datetime`. If you really want to write _the actual `datetime.datetime` object_ to a file, use the `pickle` module